# How do I make a getter in truffle?

Tags: truffle, javascript

I have a function that calls a contract and uses the return value in the code. I want to change that function so I can use it in the rest of my code as getter to my contract.

The function is asynchronous, so I can't do something like `var res = App.getter(param);`.

Looking at the other asynchronous functions like the calls, I figured I could use `.then` or promises: `ContractInstance.myFunction.call().then(function (result){ ... });`

But `App.myFunction(i).then(function (result){ ... });` doesn't work, and I don't know where to look to make it the way I want.

---

Here's the function:

```
getEventInfo: function(i){
  var numeroPlace;
  App.contracts.myContract.at(addresses[i]).then(function (instance) {
    var MyContractInstance = instance;
    MyContractInstance.getEventInfo.call().then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        //do stuff with result
        return result;
    });
  });
},
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
var eventInfo = App.getEventInfo(i);
//do stuff with eventInfo
```

or

```
App.getEventInfo(i).then(function (result){
  var eventInfo = result
  //do stuff with eventInfo
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you have truffle setup, you can use `[CONTRACT].deployed()` which is a promise that returns the instance, and you can opt to use `then/catch` or `async/await` (my preferred method if you are using ES6).

```
// async / await

contract.deployed().then(async (instance) => {
  const get = await instance.myFunction({ from: account })
  // ...additional code here.
})


// .then/.catch

contract.deployed().then((instance) => {
  instance.myFunction({ from: account }).then((data) => {
    // ...additional code here.
  })
})
```

---

Response to EDIT:

Ahh, gotcha. You simply need to nest your returns.

```
getEventInfo: function(i){
  // var numeroPlace;
  return App.contracts.myContract.at(addresses[i]).then(function (instance) {
    return instance.getEventInfo.call()
  }).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    //do stuff with result
    return result;
  });
}
```

...but since you are now essentially returning a promise, `var eventInfo = App.getEventInfo(i);` will have to change to wait for that promise to resolve.

`var eventInfo = await App.getEventInfo(i);` will do that for you, but, wherever this is called must be inside of an `async` parent function. So if you set this eventInfo variable inside of a function called loadEvent, then:

```
async function loadEvent() {
  // ...additional stuff here.
  var eventInfo = await App.getEventInfo(i);
  // ...additional stuff here.
}
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: I edited the question to add my functions, it's much more clearer. The function already works, but I'd like to use it as a function that returns something, not do the work inside the function.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat gotcha. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. I made `async` work with the example in the docs but it doesn't work with my function. First `eventInfo` is set to `undefined`, **then** after some time `getEventInfo()` returns its value. Do you have an idea why that's happening?

Comment: Does `App.getEventInfo()` need to be async too? `await` clearly doesn't wait for it to finish. Or maybe have a promise in it? It's just a function call so maybe it doesn't appear as asynchronous.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Edited `getEventInfo`. It was not waiting for the return inside the `getEventInfo.call()`. Had to pass the `getEventInfo.call()` promise in a subsequent promise chain.

Comment: Thanks! Now that I see it, it makes sense that when I make an anonymous function, the return is only a return of that function, so if I want to make the main function return something I write as many returns as they are functions.